# Mapstruct Field name "nName" not recognized

Tags: java, spring-boot

im using mastruct 1.5.5.FINAL

"nName" should recognized as nName cause it's camel case but it's now recognized as "NName".

So I need to add custom mapping. Is this not a camel case?

Entity:

```
String nName
```

DTO:

```
String nName
```

Comment: Share your full code such as the entire DTO and getter/setters and also mapstruct itself.